# Why are the noise input and noise output the same in a two-port network consisting of a passive, lossy component?

Tags: noise, microwave

I am reading *Microwave Engineering* from Pozar, chapter *Noise and Nonlinear Distortion*.

It says in the book:

> Because the entire system is in thermal equilibrium at the temperature T, and has a driving point impedance of R, the output noise power must be N<sub>o</sub> = kTB

In my opinion, N<sub>i</sub> is input noise.  When it goes through a passive, lossy component N<sub>o</sub> should be less than N<sub>i</sub>. If lines add their own noise, then N0 should be 2KTB. Why does the book does say N<sub>o</sub> = N<sub>i</sub>?

[image: Diagram image]

Comment: What is lossy about the t-line in the picture?

Comment: Because the lossy component - a resistor - is also a noise source. It attenuates the input noise and adds its own. In a matched system, the output's source impedance - and therefore noise - is the same as the input source impedance ( both R)

Comment: @user_1818839:  You should make this an answer.

Comment: @user_1818839: thank you for answering the question. but then N0 should be 2KTB since it adds its own noise?